# How to use MPI (openMPI or MPICH2) with minGW - GNU gfortran compiler

Tags: eclipse, mpi, fortran90, gfortran, openmpi

I am using the eclipse PTP IDE to develop MPI code, I want to be able to compile MPI on windows, it seems to provide c++ and c binding, but I am writing using fortran and gfortran compiler and would like to work in windows, the current problem doesn't exist on linux because there it is possible to compile the libraries locally in linux and use the .mod modules.

I wanted to compile the modules using cygwin but the GNU gfortran version on cygwin is too old, and I wasn't successful openMPI or MPICH2 on windows using miniGW

any suggestions? maybe using c++ binding in fortran 2003, I write my code in fortran 2003 so it support this feature.

Documentation on this issue is lacking.

Thank you.

Comment: In the title you state that you are using miniGW (should this be minGW?) but in the question you say you wish to use cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MPICH2 Installer's Guide](ftp://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/mpi/mpich2-doc-install.pdf) MPICH2 can be built under cygwin (see section 9.3 of the same document), so the version of gfortran shouldn't be an issue. Have you followed the instructions in this document (in particular section 2)?